# Parallel Combine two query result based on one criteria

Tags: mysql, join

I have two different queries and i want to combine first query result with the second query but want to add Overtime column should be parallel combine with first query result:
First query

```
    SELECT  count(PTPK)/2 TotalDays, PTPK, pro.Name as ProjectName FROM switch_person
                    left JOIN projects pro
                    ON pro.PK = PTPK
                    WHERE SwitchDate BETWEEN '2020-01-01' AND '2020-01-03'
                    AND PTPK <> 0 
group by ptpk
```

second Query

```
SELECT PTPK, Sum(vpo.Option-1) TotalDaysWithOvertime from switch_person sp
Left JOIN vote_poll vp
ON vp.AskDate = sp.SwitchDate
Left JOin vote_poll_output vpo
ON vpo.QuesNo = VPPK
AND vpo.EmpPK = EmployeeNamePK
WHERE SwitchDate Between '2020-01-01' AND '2020-01-03'
AND vpo.Output = 'true'
and Half = 2
group by PTPK
```

base on PTPK combine first query result with sceond but add TotaldaywithOvertime side by side to first query result with matched PTPK.

Answer (score 0):

Join the queries on their common `PTPK` column:

```
select q1.*, q2.TotalDaysWithOvertime 
from (
  <1st query here>
) q1 inner join  (
  <2nd query here>
) q2 on q2.PTPK = q1.PTPK
```

Depending on your actual data you may need a `LEFT` or `RIGHT` join instead of `INNER`.